# TypeScript not correctly inferring Return type of Union

Tags: typescript

I don't know if this syntax is correct or there's a better way of doing it.
I'm try to get TypeScript to correctly get the return type of a function that returns another function.

```
    type A = () => void;
    type B = (id: number) => void;
    type C = (id: number, title: string) => void;

    type D = A | B | C;
    interface Funcs {
      [key: string]: (fn) => D
    }
```

Funcs is an object that contains a bunch of functions and it returns a function of Types A, B or C. For example:

```
 {
   addPerson: (fn) => () => return fn(add());
   deletePerson: (fn) => (id) => return fn(delete(id));
   updatePerson: (fn) => (id, title) => return fn(update(id, title));
 }
```

When I try calling One of the functions. The signature of the return type is confused

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I made a typo and didn't notice. The update is more closer to what I want

Comment: 1. What type is `fn`? And are all the `fn`s the same type? 2. Why are you returning the result of calling `fn` when the function doing so has a `void` return type? 3. Please fix the various syntax errors unrelated to the question (missing `{}` on the arrow functions [or remove `return`], `;` where `,` is expected in the obj literal, using keyword `delete` as a fn name, ...). 4. Are you using `Funcs` in the var that refers to the object you've shown? Taking the time to write your question clearly and completely, without obvious syntax errors unrelated to it, would help you get useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't infer those return types if you use `Funcs`. But you probably don't need `Funcs`.

There are several syntax errors etc. in the question, but if I make reasonable assumptions I think you meant something like this:

```typescript
type A = () => void;
type B = (id: number) => void;
type C = (id: number, title: string) => void;
type D = A | B | C;

type FnParamType = unknown;

type Fn = (param: FnParamType) => void;

declare const addSomething: () => FnParamType;
declare const deleteSomething: (id: number) => FnParamType;
declare const updateSomething: (id: number, title: string) => FnParamType;

interface Funcs {
    [key: string]: (fn: Fn) => D;
}
const fns: Funcs = {
    addPerson: (fn) => () => { fn(addSomething()); },
    deletePerson: (fn) => (id: number) => { fn(deleteSomething(id)); },
    updatePerson: (fn) => (id: number, title: string) => { fn(updateSomething(id, title)); },
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UAUBKBA+KA3A9gSwBMBuAKFEigCEFlCAuKAOwFcBbAIwgCc15NdCpctADCNJPSZtOXADRRgeYABsIDAM7AueRgHNe-fMTLhoAERpwAPlSg2RpExQBijAAoBDLh9YAVUzTMjADWjDgA7oyOwlCu4mBePgyunt5+pgbYRo4EEADGyl7QeTiMmlAeBAQAyjisEMAAFjq6DKgYse6J6ZCkuQVFUCVlwFC5qsAQtfVNLW2SLBzcmSnd-r0k-YVcxaXlzGAEHpPTDc168wQMizLyiipqUJraeitdaesQjjqTXABmHjy0GcQTy6igAG8SFAYVAANrBCAgDRaFoAXTaf0YyUYmTMpAAviRhuUsepkqDwYgobCKlU3Nx1KVMbiOu0+JCoFikJUanUzi1UCgiFACbJobDxg0IAyuEzscgsZkJFcpEseB0IVzGEgpSd+bM9CqUMLReLaQcjpNZfKWcqFtJuHclKoUS99JrtUhLccpgbzroVc6HiaRWKSATSEA)

There's just nothing for TypeScript to use to differentiate what those functions return, all of your functions accept `fn` (which you haven't typed, but I'm guessing they're all the same type). TypeScript simply can't infer that one of them is going to return `() => void` while another returns `(id: number) => void`, etc.

But if you don't use `Funcs`, TypeScript will correctly type `addPerson` etc.:

```typescript
const fns = {
    addPerson: (fn: Fn) => () => { fn(addSomething()); },
    deletePerson: (fn: Fn) => (id: number) => { fn(deleteSomething(id)); },
    updatePerson: (fn: Fn) => (id: number, title: string) => { fn(updateSomething(id, title)); },
};

// These all work fine and have appropriate parameter hints:
fns.addPerson((param: FnParamType) => {})();
fns.deletePerson((param: FnParamType) => {})(42);
fns.updatePerson((param: FnParamType) => {})(42, "answer");
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UAUBKBA+KA3A9gSwBMBuAKFEigCEFlCAuKAOwFcBbAIwgCc15NdCpctADCNJPSZtOXADRRgeYABsIDAM7AueRgHNe-fMTLhoAERpwAPlSg2RpExQBijAAoBDLh9YAVUzTMjADWjDgA7oyOwlCu4mBePgyunt5+pgbYRo4EEADGyl7QeTiMmlAeBAQAyjisEMAAFjq6DKgYse6J6ZCkuQVFUCVlwFC5qsAQtfVNLW2SLBzcmSnd-r0k-YVcxaXlzGAEHpPTDc168wQMizLyiipqUJraeitdaesQjsPlAGZlNAA3iQoKCKlU3Nx1KU2v9koxMu0+FBAVB-khKjU6mcWqgUEQoABfWQgsHjBoQSFcaGMWG0zqIhbSZYdVHo8knbGzPQSAgofFEklgqAHI6TKk0unwxlXKRLOQKJSqDRaFqZNmMJCi45TLnnXS8u5KiD8gnEkiExz-dQAOkxEtKSCQCTS8NSPk+6sJKFQpGtNo5lKhjud3TdawyrO9SAALAAmfEkf3a8XBzWh12dd09E1Rn3x+QAIg8ZXC3ELiaAA)

Answer (score 0):

Your types and your object are different types. It is hard to understand which of two you exactly want, so there are few possible solutions.

1. Assuming types are correct, editing object

```js
type A = () => void;
type B = (id: number) => void;
type C = (id: number, title: string) => void;

type D = A | B | C;
interface Funcs {
  [key: string]: () => D
}

const Q: Funcs = {
    addPerson: () => () => {},
    deletePerson: () => (id) => {},
    updatePerson: () => (id, title) => {},
}

Q.updatePerson()(1, 'title') // example call
```

2. Assuming object is correct, editing types

```js
type A = () => () => void;
type B = (id: number) => () => void;
type C = (id: number, title: string) => () => void;

type D = A | B | C;
interface Funcs {
  [key: string]: D
}

const Q: Funcs = {
    addPerson: () => () => {},
    deletePerson: (id) => () => {},
    updatePerson: (id, title) => () => {},
}

Q.updatePerson(1, 'title')() // example call
```

3. And simplest one, just in case you actually didn't want functions inside functions, because it doesn't seem it needs it..

```js
type A = () => void;
type B = (id: number) => void;
type C = (id: number, title: string) => void;

type D = A | B | C;
interface Funcs {
  [key: string]: D
}

const Q: Funcs = {
    addPerson: () => {},
    deletePerson: (id) => {},
    updatePerson: (id, title) => {},
}

Q.updatePerson(1, 'title') // example call
```

*Note, I used empty body function (`{}`) instead of your code for functions. It is hard to say why you do `return delete(id);` instead of just `delete(id)` in here, but it seems like it is reduced example.*

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have to define it correctly. `Funcs` is an interface that contains a `dictionary` definition. The value type of this dictionary object defined as follows;

```
() => D
```

where the type D is a union of;

```
type A = () => void;
type B = (id: number) => void;
type C = (id: number, title: string) => void;

type D = A | B | C;
```

That means, it will accept a function with the different argument bodies and returns nothing.

In your given example;

```
 {
   addPerson: () => () => return add();
   deletePerson: (id) => () => return delete(id);
   updatePerson: (id, title) => () => return update(id, title
 }
```

the return types for the given values matches with your union type(*most probably, but we don't know the actual implementation of add, delete or update functions, I assume they return nothing*), however the function parameters does not for any of the examples. To achieve what you wanna achive, you have to specify an additional type like so;

```
type X = () => D;
type Y = (id: number) => D;
type Z = (id: number, title: string) => D;

type T = X | Y | Z;


interface Funcs {
  [key: string]: T
}
```

Now, you have a dictionary type named `T` that accepts functions with 3 different argument body and each one of them returns another function with the type `D`.